# Spring Batch: Use of ExcecutionContext to pass step attributes

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin, spring-framework-beans

I have some spring batch jobs with number of steps which takes variable amount of time to run. I now need to define thresholds for each step  to check if its run crosses threshold time.

I was thinking of somehow passing this value  to ExcecutionContext  of StepExecution class.

I have gone through https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/configureJob.html and other docs to find out how values are passed ExcecutionContext, but couldn't find anything.

Can anyone help me understand how ExcecutionContext for StepExecution is initialized and can I pass some custom parameters at each step definition?

Comment: Do you mean like you want to set threshold for each step in your process? So if the time exceeds the threshhold what do you expect the framework to do?

Comment: Lookup TimeoutTerminationPolicy; it applies to chunks

Comment: @pvpkiran Yes, thats right. I want to treat this data as META data for step and we have UI console using spring-batch-admin REST API to monitor if steps crosses thresholds, so that we can generate reports for step level execution time against thresholds.

Comment: Why isn't this just configured as a Spring property?

Comment: @MichaelMinella: Can you give example how this can be done at each step.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar situation in our project and we did pass values through steps through jobParameters and modified or added the value in the job parameters like this

```
chunkContext.getStepContext().getStepExecution().getJobParameters().getParameters().put("THRESHOLD", "VALUE")
```

and in the StepListener we did check or retrieve this value and did some processing accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But we have specific requirement for each step with different thresholds. I want to understand is there any way we can pass parameters at step level rather than hard coding it in java code?

Comment: I do not understand your requirement.. the snippet actually do not hard-code .. it is just adding a new key/value in the jobParameters inside the step..